# Remove selected date from a month calendar control

Tags: c#, winforms, calendar, controls

On my form I have a clear button that is supposed to reset the form back to it's original settings, and as such, I need to de-select any dates a user has selected on my month calendar, but cannot figure out how to do this.

So, is there a way to remove all dates selected by the user on a month calendar?

Comment: In the future, please be sure to tag the UI framework you are using (Winforms, Webforms, MVC, Silverlight, etc...)

Comment: What do you mean by 'user has selected'? Clicked with a mouse and picked some date? Please, clarify. Adding some relevant code would also help.

Comment: No. What he means is some way of resetting the calendar control so that none of the dates are highlighted. I am after the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Selection start and end to a specific date.

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
monthCalendar1.SelectionStart = today;
monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd = today;
```

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.removeallboldeddates.aspx

Or something like this:

```
calendar.SetDate(DateTime.Now)
```